# Unable to Start Azure Kali Linux VM - NetworkingInternalOperationError

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I am unable to start my Azure Kali Linux VM. 
The VM was working yesterday and was shutdown yesterday. The Azure console shows it as stopped(deallocated). When I try to start the VM it fails with the error "Provisioning failed. An unexpected error occured while processing the network profile of the VM. Please retry later.. NetworkingInternalOperationError"

When in the failed state, if I select stop I get the same error.

I am unable to edit any network settings or disk resize settings as it thinks the VM is in still in use. Setting the scheduled autoshutdown also doesn't work.

Six hours later, what have I missed? How can I properly stop and restart the VM?

Comment: Open a support case? Or, make a snapshot of the disk en re-provision the VM. Then, swap the disk to your snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redeploy the VM. Works in many cases.

[image: Azure vm redeploy]

Or resize the VM temporarily to a bigger size, it will redeploy the VM as well to another host. I think the underlying host is the problem in your case.